# Call python function from within Java

Tags: python, java, groovy

I am building a workflow in an online tool that uses script tasks (Java / Groovy). In this workflow, the user defines some string that has to be processed. Processing has to be done within a Python script.

So let's say the user defines the string: "This is a test string."
Then this string will be fed to the script task, which is in Java or Groovy. This script task will have to push the string to a python function, somewhere outside of the system. The python function will push back a result to the Java script task, like 50% or something. This will be used later in the code.

I was thinking about API's, but I have no idea how to build this. Any other ideas or some help in building my first API?

Edit:
So as an example lets say I built a python script, called wordCounter.py
It looks like this:

```py
def getWordCount(string):
    return len(string.split())
```

The function counts the number of words present in the string. So for "This is a string." the result would be 4.
Now I want my java script to be able to call this function. So, in java I define the string, pass it to the python function and retrieve the answer. It looks something like this:

```java
String testing = "This is a string."
int count = getWordCount(testing)
```

The second part is incorrect, since the function is unavailable within the java script.

I know that for the example it can be done entirely in Java, but my real code is much more complex. (It contains a Neural Network among others.)

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Easiest would probably be to just call the Python script via a `ProcessBuilder` and communicate via stdin/stdout

Comment: @aled Just edited original post.

Answer (score 1):

So here are some ideas. Exec'ing a separate python process.  With Groovy you can do this:

```
String output = "python myPython.py ${arg1} ${arg2} ${arg3}".execute().text
```

In Java 9+

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("python", "myPython.py", arg1, arg2, arg3).start();
process.waitFor( 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
InputStream stream = process.getInputStream();
String output = new String(stream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

A word of warning I provide no real error handling.  If the process tosses an exception or python can't be found, etc.  This will produce unexpected behavior.  If you use this code you'll want to harden it with better error handling.

The next idea is to run a python web application hosting your python script in something like Flask.  Then hit that web app from Java / Groovy using an HTTP client.  There are a couple of benefits I can see with this approach.  If you are running it as a web service it only consumes a single python process.  If you are exec'ing commands from within a JVM process it might startup lots of python processes for each innovation of the script.  This centralizes the python process and allows multiple clients to invoke the script so a bit lower overhead.  It's also a bit easier to pass JSON input and output to the process, but you could do that with the CLI option as well.  You'd just have to pass that through STDIN and STDOUT of the python process.

You could also invoke it as an AWS Lambda service if you're running on AWS, and the JVM side wouldn't care if it was a Flask app or Lambda.

Comment: We are in fact running on AWS. If I understand correctly, I can store my python script on AWS Lambda and then call this script from within a Java / Groovy script?

Comment: Not handling the error input stream can also cause the process to hang.

Comment: @Wilko yes you can create your program as a lambda script in python.  Then attach a gateway to it and invoke it like a rest api.  That would be pretty simple to do.

Comment: @Wilko, if you have ability to host your python as a lambda - then you can call it from any language (including groovy) as an api